# Design pattern for activities

Tags: php, design-patterns

Let's say I have multiple activities with same events and these events having different parameters in each activity. The question is "Is there any design pattern that particularly cover this matter?"

If I use `interfaces`, then I have to have same parameters in event functions. What I need is just insuring of having all event functions with any parameters in each activity.

Example:

```php
class FirstCampaign{
    public function onFirstPurchase($arg1,$arg2, User $user){
        //
    }
    public function onFirstTrade($price,$something, User $user,Model $model){
        //
    }
}

class SecondCampaign{
    public function onFirstPurchase(User $user){
        //
    }
    public function onFirstTrade(Model $model){
        //
    }
}

class ThirdCampaign{
    public function onFirstPurchase(User $user, Model $model, int $abc){
        //
    }
    public function onFirstTrade(){
        //
    }
}
```

PS. I have tried `onFirstPurchase(...$arguments)` but it's not exactly what I need and it's just too complicated to work with.

PS. I call the events in different part of my application and they are not running under same circumstances.

Comment: have you looked at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: see the [parameter object pattern](http://principles-wiki.net/patterns:parameter_object) - use this and an interface